# How can I upgrade my iPhone to iOS 11 after accidentally declining the TOS?

Tags: upgrade, ios, iphone

The other night I wanted to install iOS 11 on my 6s+ overnight, but I had to accept the Terms of Service to do the installation.  I woke up at 5, had to be up by 5:45, and didn't want to miss out on 45 minutes of sleep. I did not want to start the installation for fear of my alarm not going off due to the update. When I was fumbling around with my phone I accidentally clicked the install option, which took me to the Accept Terms of Service screen. I tried to exit out of that screen, but couldn't. So I hit Decline. Now when I go to Settings -> General -> Software Update, it says my software is up to date (10.3.2).

How can I fix this situation and upgrade my iOS now?

Comment: instead of going with the over the air update, perhaps you can try installing via iTunes. Does the upgrade button show up when connected to your computer via USB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got off the phone with Apple Support:  Do a Forced Restart (hold power button & home button until Apple logo appears then release.)  Now go back to Settings>General>Software Update.

Comment: I was hoping to verify your answer before accepting, but I ended up installing the new update. I wasn’t presented with a chance to decline the TOS. Thank you for contacting Apple and sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a good solution, but when Apple releases another update you get another chance to update your phone.